# ffmpeg inside nginx-rtmp module doesn't work when scaling video

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx, rtmp, hls

So I setup an nginx RTMP server using [this rtmp module](https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module). Below is my nginx.conf that I made following [this guide](https://licson.net/post/setting-up-adaptive-streaming-with-nginx/).

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }

                application movie {
                        live on;
                        record off;

                        exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/movie -async 1 -vsync -1
                                -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:v 256k -b:a 32k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie_low
                                -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:v 768k -b:a 96k -vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie_mid
                                -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:v 1024k -b:a 128k -vf "scale=960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie_high
                                -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:v 1920k -b:a 128k -vf "scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie_hd720
                                -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie_src;
                }

                application hls {
                        live on;
                        hls on;
                        hls_path /tmp/hls;
                        hls_nested on;

                        hls_variant _low BANDWIDTH=288000; # Low bitrate, sub-SD resolution
                        hls_variant _mid BANDWIDTH=448000; # Medium bitrate, SD resolution
                        hls_variant _high BANDWIDTH=1152000; # High bitrate, higher-than-SD resolution
                        hls_variant _hd720 BANDWIDTH=2048000; # High bitrate, HD 720p resolution
                        hls_variant _src BANDWIDTH=4096000; # Source bitrate, source resolution
                }
        }
}
```

For some reason, scaling the video with `-vf "scale=..."` doesn't work (same goes for using the `-s wxh` flag), as no output is created. I verify this by checking the stat page that the rtmp module provides. When I begin streaming to the server, the /movie application shows data streams, but the /hls application gets nothing. If I remove the `-vf "scale=..."` flags then everything works as expected with 5 streams under the /hls application. Am I doing something wrong? I would like to have scaling as I don't want to be sending the same resolution across different bitrates. My version of nginx is 1.16.1, and this is all running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I have no idea where to find the logs, I tried `cat` on `/var/log/nginx/` for access.log and error.log and both are empty. I tried `journalctl -u nginx` and that only shows a ton of "Started nginx - high performance web server.". I even put `-loglevel verbose` in the ffmpeg command and I still get nothing. Is there something extra I have to do to enable logging in nginx?

Comment: Edit: Found where the logs were being stored, here's a pastebin of my last 1000 lines: https://pastebin.com/B0f290mW 
However that doesn't mention anything about ffmpeg. When I do `cat log | grep exec` I see things like this: `child 'ffmpeg' started pid=11536` followed a few lines later by `child 11536 exited; ignoring,` Grep for ffmpeg just shows a bunch of the child ffmpeg starting messages.

Comment: Does it work when running ffmpeg normally on the command line, on your server? If it does not, then the problem is that your options are wrong and ffmpeg isn't starting. However if it does work with these exact options in the terminal, then it's likely to be something with the syntax that doesn't translate well into nginx config.

Comment: Or… could it be that "scale" and "copy" don't really go together?

either way if you run it in the shell, you'll get better error messages which will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @BenXO Running it in command line solved it! The issue was that libvo_aacenc is no longer supported by default on ffmpeg as they use a different one internally now. Changing it to aac got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the ffmpeg command in the command line as per @BenXO's suggestion, I got an error about libvo_aacenc not found, i.e. this snippet was the issue: `-c:a libvo_aacenc`. A quick search yielded that ffmpeg no longer supports this encoder and it's recommended to just use `aac`. Changing all instances of `-c:a libvo_aacenc` to `-c:a aac` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    }

http {

    keepalive_timeout   60;
    send_timeout        10;
    keepalive_requests  10;
    client_body_timeout 10;

    #gzip       on;
    sendfile        on;
    include     mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    server {

    listen      80;
    # listen [::]:  80 ipv6only;

    server_name localhost;
    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;";
    index index.php index-nginx.html index.html index.htm index.m3u8 index.mpd;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root   site;
        }

        # location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include        fastcgi_params;
    #   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #   }

    location / {
        location ~* \.m3u8$ {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Strict-Transport-Security' 'max-age=31536000';
        add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' "nosniff" 'always';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        # add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }

        root site;
        index index.php index.html index-nginx.html index.htm index.m3u8 index.mpd;
        }

        location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        # auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        # auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        }

        location /stat.xsl {
        root site;
        }

        #location /control {
        #rtmp_control all;
        # auth_basic "stream";
        # auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        #}

        #location /publish {
        #    return 201;
        #}
        #location /play {
        #    return 202;
        #}
        #location /record_done {
        #    return 203;
        #}
        
    location /tmp_hls {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
        types {
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        text/html html;
        }
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_localtime on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        alias X:/temp/tmp_hls;                          # <----- 
        expires -1;
        }

    location /tmp_dash {
        alias X:/temp/tmp_dash;                         # <----- 
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_localtime on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        expires -1;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
    types {
        application/dash+xml mpd;
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        video/mp2t ts;
        text/html html;
        }
    }

    location /recordings {
        alias recordings;  
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_localtime on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        expires -1;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
        }
        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
            video/mp4 mp4;
            text/html html;
            }
        }
    }
}

rtmp {
    server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4096;

    application live {
            live on;
        interleave on;
        meta on;
        session_relay on;
        max_connections 1500;
            record_path recordings;
        record_suffix all-%d-%b-%y-%T.flv;
        # record_interval 30s;
        # record keyframes;

        push rtmp://localhost/hls;
        # push rtmp://localhost/dash;
        # push rtmp://localhost/youtube;

            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$app/$name  -async 1 -vsync -1 
            -c:v libx264 -acodec copy -b:v 256k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -g 60 -hls_list_size 0 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_low
            -c:v libx264 -acodec copy -b:v 768k -vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -g 60 -hls_list_size 0 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_mid
            -c:v libx264 -acodec copy -b:v 1024k -vf "scale=960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -g 60 -hls_list_size 0 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_high
            -c:v libx264 -acodec copy -b:v 1920k -vf "scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -g 60 -hls_list_size 0 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_higher
            -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_src;
        }
    
    application hls {
            live on;
        hls on;
        hls_nested on;
        hls_cleanup on;
        meta copy;
        # hls_sync 100ms;
        hls_type live;
        hls_fragment 1s;
        hls_playlist_length 3s;
        hls_path X:/temp/tmp_hls;                           # <----- 
        hls_fragment_naming system;

        hls_variant _low BANDWIDTH=288000;  # Low bitrate, sub-SD resolution
        hls_variant _mid BANDWIDTH=448000;  # Medium bitrate, SD resolution
        hls_variant _high BANDWIDTH=1152000;    # Higher-than-SD resolution 
        hls_variant _higher BANDWIDTH=2048000;  # High bitrate, HD 720p resolution
        hls_variant _src BANDWIDTH=4096000; # Source bitrate, source resolution
        }

    application dash {
            live on;
        dash on;
        dash_nested on;
        dash_cleanup on;
        dash_fragment 1s;
        dash_playlist_length 3s;
        dash_path X:/temp/tmp_dash;                     # <----- 
        }

    #application youtube {
            #live on;
            #push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YOUR_STREAM_KEY;
        #allow publish 127.0.0.1;
        #deny publish all;
        #}
    }
}
```